# How to generate client proxy for a WCF service to a particular location?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

How to generate client proxy for a WCF service to a particular location?

Suppose I want to create the proxy class in a folder "C:\Client\".

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

[svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) tool can help you

```
svcutil.exe /d:C:\Client\ /out:generatedProxy.cs http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know the /d switch.

Answer (score 1):

When you run svcutil.exe, you can specify the output location using the o switch:

```
svcutil.exe whatever.wsdl /o:C:\Client\Services.cs
```

(Should be something like that, but maybe you have to quote the full path or something)